# Extract a substring from value of key-value pair using regex

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I have a string in log and I want to mask values based on regex.

**For example**:

```
"email":"testEmail@test.com", "phone":"1111111111", "text":"sample text may contain email testEmail@test.com as well"
```

The regex should mask

1. email value - both inside the string after "email" and "text"
2. phone number

**Desired output**:

```
"email":"*****", "phone":"*****", "text":"sample text may contain email ***** as well"
```

What I have been able to do is to mask email and phone individually but not the email id present inside the string after "text".

**Regex developed so far**:

```
(?<=\"(?:email|phone)\"[:])(\")([^\"]*)(\")
```

https://regex101.com/r/UvDIjI/2/

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regex? Either way perhaps the simplest thing to do if you're going down this route is to capture the email and replace it globally.

Comment: Do you want to mask *every* email iniside `text` or just the one that corresponds to `email` ? What programming language are you using?

Comment: @DipeshGupta Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes it did. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not matching an email address in the first part by matching not a double quote, you could match the email address in the text by also not matching a double quote.

One way to do this could be to get the matches using lookarounds and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Then replace the matches with `*****`

Note that you don't have to escape the double quote and the colon could be written without using the character class.

```
(?<="(?:phone|email)":")[^"]+(?=")|[^@"\s]+@[^@"\s]+
```

Explanation

- `(?<="(?:phone|email)":")` Assert what is on the left is either "phone":" or "email":"
- `[^"]+(?=")` Match not a double quote and make sure that there is one at the end
- `|` Or
- `[^@"\s]+@[^@"\s]+` Match an `email like` pattern by making use of a negated character class matching not a double quote or @

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PyPzzz/1)

Answer (score 0):

## [Meta Sequence Word Boundary `\b`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) & [Alternation `|`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

The input string pattern has either quotes or spaces wrapped around the targets which both are considered non-words. So this: "`\b`*emailPattern*`\b`" and this: *space*`\b`*emailPattern*`\b`*space* are matches. The alternation gives one line the power of two lines. Search for *emailPattern* ***OR*** *phonePattern*.

> ```
> /(\b\w+?@\w+?\.\w+?\b|[0-9]{10})/g;
> ```

- `(`Word boundary (a non-word on the left) `\b`
- One or more word characters `\w+?`
- Literal `@`
- One or more word characters `\w+?`
- Escaped literal `.`
- One or more word characters `\w+?`
- Word boundary (a non-word on the right) `\b`
- **OR** `|`
- 10 consecutive numbers `[0-9]{10}` `)`
- `g`lobal flag continues search after first match.

### Demo

```js
let str = `"email":"testEmail@test.com", "phone":"1111111111", "text":"sample text may contain email testEmail@test.com as well"`;

const rgx = /(\b\w+?@\w+?\.\w+?\b|[0-9]{10})/g;

let res = str.replace(rgx, '*****');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current RegEx is trying to accomplish too much in a single take. You'd be better off splitting the conditions and dealing with them separately. I'll assume that the input will always follow the structure of your example, no edge cases:

1. Emails:

   - `\w+@.+?(?="|\s)` - In emails, every character preceded by `@` is always a word character, so using `\w+@` is enough to capture the first half of the email. As for the second half, I used a wildcard (`.`) with a lazy quantifier (`+?`) to stop the capture as soon as possible and combined it with a positive lookahead that checks for double quotes or whitespaces (`(?="|\s)`) so to capture both the e-mails inside `"email"` and `"text"` properties. [Lookarounds are zero-length assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and thus they don't get captured.
2. Phone number:

   - `(?<="phone":")\d+` - Here I just use the prefix `"phone":"` in a lookbehind and then capture only digits `\d+`.

Combine both conditions and you have your RegEx: `\w+@.+?(?="|\s)|(?<="phone":")\d+`.

**Regex101:** https://regex101.com/r/UvDIjI/3